# Are class member enums thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Take the following as an example

```
public class MyClass
{
      private MyEnum _sharedEnumVal { get; set; }
}
```

If methods within MyClass ran on different threads and read/updated _sharedEnumVal, am I right in saying that a lock, or other mechanism, would be required to keep the variable thread safe like other primitives or are enums special?

Thanks

Comment: what makes you think its thread safe? its just a primitive underneath.

Comment: enums are just integers under the covers

Comment: Yea you need a lock. Here is a good article about thread safe enumerations http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56575/Thread-safe-enumeration-in-C

Comment: @CraigW., not always. It is just Int32 by default

Comment: I don't see how updating an `enum` would be any different from updating any other value.

Comment: Thread-safety is a property of **code**, not variables.  The only guarantee you get for an enum is that it is atomic, that's not nearly good enough.  The code that accesses an object of MyClass must arbitrate access when necessary.  It will be necessary when threads both read and write that property.

Comment: As Hans says, "thread safe" is a property of the code. More to the point, until you tell us what _kind_ of thread-safety it is you are looking for, it's not possible to answer your question. Depending on how it's used, your `_sharedEnumVal` property could in fact be completely thread-safe. Or it might be a complete disaster. See Eric Lippert's classic [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe/) for an excellent discussion of the topic, which may help you present your question in an answerable way

Comment: You possibly miss understood Peter. I said "ran on different threads and read/updated" which indicates both read and write concurrently for the sake of argument. The question was merely because I was led to believe enums are special which they clearly aren't. Thank you all for answering however

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: I'm aware that Int32 is the default. However, only integral types are allowed (i.e. byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong) so the sentiment (that they are backed by a primitive type) still applies. And I'd be willing to bet if you interviewed 10 .NET developers less than half of them could tell you that you can specify the backing type for an enum.

Comment: @CraigW., The reason I've mentioned about backing type is the topic of question because from point of view atomicity (which is important concept when building thread-safe code) it is very important.

Comment: @HansPassant Out of curiosity, why is being atomic read/write (assuming we use the default `Int32`) not good enough? Seems to me that it is sufficient for an enum property, since enums are not mutable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thread-safety is a tricky subject. The updates to the enum are always atomic. So even if thousands of threads try to update the same enum at once, you will never get an invalid, half-updated enum value. The value itself will always be valid. But even when you update the enum it is never guaranteed that other threads would read the "latest" value due to cache-incoherency between multiple cores. To ensure that all cores are synchronized you would need a memory barrier.

But even that is not the guarantee of thread-safety because data races can still happen. Say you have this logic somewhere in your class:

```
 public void DoSomething()
 {
    if (_sharedEnumVal == MyEnum.First) {
       DoPrettyThings();
    } else {
       DoUglyThings();
    }
 }

 public void UpdateValue(MyEnum newValue)
 {
     _sharedEnumVal = newValue;
 }
```

and you have these two different threads:

```
 static MyClass threadSafeClass = new MyClass();

 void ThreadOne()
 {
    while (true) 
    {
        threadSafeClass.UpdateValue(MyEnum.Second);
        DoSomething();
    }
 }

 void ThreadTwo()
 {
    while (true)
    {
       threadSafeClass.UpdateValue(MyEnum.First);
       DoSomething();
    }
 }
```

Here, although the updates to the enum are atomic, two threads will be "racing" to change and use enum value to their own purposes and when DoSomething is called, there is no guarantee what value the enum would have. You would get completely unexpected results. ThreadTwo might cause pretty things and ThreadOne would cause ugly things to happen, the exact opposite of what's expected.

In that case you would still need locking to ensure thread-safety of the class behavior.

Comment: Good answer :-).
I would also mention in that regard `volatile` and `Interlocked.MemoryBarrier()` that can also do the trick without locking.

Answer (score 4):

I failed to understand, why this topic was downvoted:).
There are some good points and some bad ideas and some even upvoted here!
So let's sort the bits.

The question here is actually about atomicity.
If the operation is atomic, then it is inherently thread-safe without locking for some operations like read/write and other operations allowed thanks to Interlocked class for given type.

Now, .Net is stating, that int read/write is atomic. Same for all types that fit into 32bit's, 64bit types are not atomic! read/write of the object reference is atomic too.

Some operations are atomic, some not, like increment, unless you are calling Interlocked.Increment.

Now why I talk about int? Well by default, enum is of type int, 32bit, unless explicitly specified otherwise.

That means, that reading/writing is atomic => thread-safe.

Btw, it is usually a bad idea to keep a naked property, I would rather use variable behind the property and play with the variable because it is necessary to use Interlocked methods.

There are many useful ways where atomicity is good enough guarantee to work with without locking. For example background thread status. Or a property that allowing background workers to work, until it is changed to some expected value, providing info for background workers to stop etc.

Also, Interlocked class is extending these scenarios for shared iterating variable and many more.

As Chris Hannon noted, the simple read/write can lead to the stale as data won't be updated unless specifically read/write operations would be decorated by memory barrier or Interlocked operations would be used, Interlocked.Add for reading, interlocked.CompareExchange for writing, where caches will be updated.
Thanks to Chris for good point I missed!

Comment: Atomicity alone is almost never a "good enough guarantee" and both of your examples of being "good enough" have issues with stale data. Thread 1 is doing work, watching a shared variable X. Thread 2 changes variable X to an expected value. Thread 1 continues to work forever, because it has no good reason to go back to main memory to refresh its value and continues relying on its stale, cached version instead. The code is now broken (possibly! sometimes! under certain conditions!) and is never "good enough".

Comment: Did you note,that I was specifically talking about Interlocked as well?Yes, simple read/write is dangerous with stale unless it would be decorated by memory barrier,but Interlocked operations are not, they update the cache.For example,Interlocked.Add can read the variable,if it adds zero,returning back original last value of the variable. CompareExchange can be used to set requested value. So it is atomic and in the same time, there is no stale issue. Still far better than a lock, but sure, it is all about knowing what one does. Btw thanks for the good point I missed.